Seeking a children's illustrated sci-fi fantasy "Where's Wally" puzzle book
This book was published some time in the UK between the 80's and 90's, and is set in a fictional star system where the good planets are being rapidly overwhelmed by evil invaders. The book is completely linear and the challenge is to spot as many as the instructions provide.
The art is pulp style (think Heavy Metal) and the illustrations often feature futuristic technology and bizarre worlds. It is not Patrick Burston's The Planet of Terror or a choose-your-own-adventure book, but it is definitely science fiction/fantasy.
I believe they were part of a series but can't remember anything else, other than that the books were shaped as landscape, as opposed to portrait. And there were circles or shapes that acted as "lifeforce". I may have gotten some of this wrong; can anyone shed a clue?
